# UISearchBar's scope button won't show up iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I know this question was asked several times before, and it was solved(Before I was using that solution with iOS4 and 5). My recent project involves using `UISearchBar` with some other views, and I want to show it's scope buttons when it becomes active. Before, in `UISearchBardelegate`'s `- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` I was doing

```
[searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
[searchBar sizeToFit];
```

and it was showing scope buttons. But now, on iOS6 this code does nothing. `UISearchBar` is added in IB, it's delegate is set to my view controller. 
Anybody has solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem was with iOS 6 auto layout thing, once I'va removed it, problem was gone. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like what's going on is that the `UISearchBar` is failing to invalidate its intrinsic content size when it shows and hides the scope bar.

Until it's fixed in UIKit, it's extremely easy to work around it by simply subclassing `UISearchBar` and overriding a single method:

```
- (void)setShowsScopeBar:(BOOL)showsScopeBar {
  if ([self showsScopeBar] != showsScopeBar) {
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
  }
  [super setShowsScopeBar:showsScopeBar];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, anyways, I'll wait for autolayout thing to become more stable... Until then, see you later `autoLayout` ;)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Such an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

I reported this as a bug to Apple and got an answer how to fix it:

Just subclass UISearchBar and override -setShowsScopeBar:

```
- (void)setShowsScopeBar:(BOOL)showsScopeBar
{
    if (self.showsScopeBar != !!showsScopeBar) [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [super setShowsScopeBar:showsScopeBar];
}
```

**UPDATE**: This is fixed in iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this in iOS 6.0 without having to subclass UISearchBar is just by adjusting the frame size in the Search Bar Delegate:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSMutableArray *ma = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];

    [ma addObject:@"One"];
    [ma addObject:@"Two"];

    CGRect f = searchBar.frame;
    f.size.height += 44.0f;
    searchBar.frame = f;

    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [ma copy];
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    CGRect f = searchBar.frame;
    f.size.height -= 44.0f;
    _searchBar.frame = f;

    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = nil;
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
}
```

Comment: Consider reading other answers before posting an answer, please :)

Comment: @Fahri,, I really don't understand the point of your comment. I did read the other answers and I offered an alternative that worked for me and may help others. What's your problem with that?

Comment: Ideally, frames aren't adjusted anymore. If possible, it is better to work with constraints so the interface is more fluid and dynamic as needed.