# Auto Layout not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, autolayout

I have a search bar on top of a table view set up using auto layout like so:

```
_searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_searchBar]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_searchBar)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tableView)]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_searchBar][_tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_searchBar, _tableView)]];
```

Everything looks nice when I run it. But when I do `_searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;` before I start editing the search bar, the search bar and table view do not resize automatically. Even when I do `[_searchBar sizeToFit]`, the table view does not resize and move down. Why??

Note: I'm not putting the search bar as the table view's header; it's just a parent view and two subviews.
Note 2: I checked the `intrinsicContentSize` of `_searchBar` before and after I call `_searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;` and the size does indeed change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [searchBar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    [searchBar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

See [UISearchBar's scope button won't show up iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009095/uisearchbars-scope-button-wont-show-up-ios6)

Comment: So this is an Apple bug, right? Btw, those `sizeToFit`s aren't needed.

Comment: @fumoboy007 Regarding those `sizeToFit` references, you're correct that those aren't needed and I've removed them. Thanks.